# php whatsapp sharing not sending entire link

Tags: php, whatsapp, sharing

I'm trying to share the entire link via `whatsapp`.  Suppose I have the link on my browser as:

```
http://www.foo.com/foo?a=1&b=2
```

My normal way to share this link that I used is:

```
$actual_link="http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";     
echo "<li><a href='whatsapp://send?text=$actual_link'>Share</a></li>";
```

When I hover my mouse over the `anchor` element, it shows the link correctly, but when I click on it and get into whatsapp, the message appears as:

```
http://www.foo.com/foo?a=1
```

Why am I not getting the second variable?

Comment: Try replacing the ampersand in `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` to its entity, `&amp;`.

Comment: @chris85 it didnt work

Comment: Looking at this article, http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/use-whatsapps-url-scheme-with-drafts-launch-center-pro-or-a-bookmarklet/, seems like it needs http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this myself on my Mac with the WhatsApp desktop application and the URL is passed correctly to WhatsApp:

```
<?php

$actual_link = urlencode("http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

echo "<li><a href='whatsapp://send?text=$actual_link'>Share</a></li>"; 

?>
```

So, if I go to to the URL below and click the share link then this is exactly what I see in WhatsApp

```
http://localhost/whatsapp.php?a=1&b=2
```